# Prevent OpenAuth login if the linked MembershipUser is not approved

Tags: asp.net, webforms, asp.net-membership, dotnetopenauth

I have developed a e-mail activation system upon registering at my website. When a user registers, I set IsApproved to false. This works perfectly fine as long as I use local logins.

Here's the problem: if the user registers with OpenAuth, I create the membership user and set the IsApproved to false too - but it's still possible to log in with OpenAuth. I'm guessing the IsApproved is just for authenticating username/password.

This is part of the autogenerated login sequence of OpenAuth:

```
if (OpenAuth.Login(authResult.Provider, authResult.ProviderUserId, createPersistentCookie: false))
{
    RedirectToReturnUrl();
}
```

Basicly, what I need is to get the membership username that is associated with the OpenAuth credentials so I can check if the user is approved and act on that, but I have not been able to figure out how.

I tried looking into getting an instance of OpenAuthAccountData class for these OpenAuth credentials, but I was unable to find anything.

Comment: Cheers.. A tumbleweed badge!

Answer (score 0):

Just don't call OpenAuth.CreateUser. After the user authenticates, you can get the username using "authResult.UserName". Nothing is created in your database until you call CreateUser.